# How to pass a function as props when both Parent and Child component also a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `ParentComponent` which I want to pass a function named `toggleDrawer` to the `ChildComponent` like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () {
     
   const [drawerState, setDrawerState] = useState(false);

   const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => {
        setDrawerState(open);
   }

  return(
       <div>
         <IconButton color="primary"                         
                     onClick={toggleDrawer("right", true)}> // here I called to toggleDrawer so the ChildComponent can be shown 
             <SomeIcon />
         </IconButton>
         
        <ChildComponent 
             anchor="right"
             open={drawerState}
             handleDrawerState={toggleDrawer}/> 

        </div>
  )
}
```

So I get the `toggleDrawer` function in `ChildComponent` like this:

```
const CartDrawer = (props) => {

 // other stuff at the top 

 return(
    <Drawer
      anchor={props.anchor}
      open={props.open}
      onClose={props.handleDrawerState(props.anchor, false)}
    >
  )
}
```

As you can see I get the `handleDrawerState` in `ChildComponent` by accessing it `props`. But what I get is:

> TypeError: props.handleDrawerState is not a function

I tried below, also get the same result:

```
const {handleDrawerState} = props

 <Drawer
       ... other stuff 
   onClose={handleDrawerState(props.anchor, false)}
>
```

So I check the console in browser by `console.log(props)` , instead having a key with `handleDrawerState`, I having a object in the `props` ,which present like this:

> **proto**: Object

For now, I not understand what I doing wrong, cause as I see here, `toggleDrawer` in `ParentComponent` is a function, but passed to `ChildComponent` it become and object. Therefore I unable to access it in `props` in `ChildComponent` .

**Question:**

Therefore, what is the correct way to pass a function to `ChildComponent` ?

**Updated:**

If I do like this :

```
<Drawer
    ... some other stuff 
    onClose={() => props.handleDrawerState(props.anchor, false)}
>
```

I get the error like this:

> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of
> renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: justa note `onClose={handleDrawerState(props.anchor, false)}` will never work, as it will fire on mount. you need to do this `onClose={() => handleDrawerState(props.anchor, false)}`

Comment: You should log the props in the child component, seems impossible that the function is not there from what you've shown us.

Comment: @JoeLloyd ya I console.log(props) in child component, get the above result as stated

Comment: Is onClose an event?

Comment: @JoeLloyd is weird that, if I do `onClose={() => handleDrawerState(props.anchor, false)}` , it gives me `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` this error

Comment: i assume you're returning the component as well and giving it the proper name etc?

Comment: @A.R.SEIF what u mean `onClose()` event?

Comment: ya I return it properly @JoeLloyd

Comment: Can you update your code to show how you’re passing props to ChildComponent?

Comment: Ok..one minute, I try to edit the question again

Comment: @helloitsjoe hey sir, I updated my question for more details code

Comment: @ken . ```onClose() ``` is event in reactjs?

Comment: @A.R.SEIF  ya..I using React material ui, which `onClose` is stand for this `Signature:
function(event: object) => void
event: The event source of the callback.` as their documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## They need to be wrapped in an anon function

You cannot call a function as a prop if you fire the function when adding it as a prop (unless you want the result of the fired function passed as a prop).

Should be this

```
const ParentComponent = () {
     
   const [drawerState, setDrawerState] = useState(false);

   const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => {
        setDrawerState(open);
   }

  return(
       <div>
         <IconButton color="primary"                         
                     onClick={() => toggleDrawer("right", true)}> //anon func here
             <SomeIcon />
         </IconButton>
         
        <CartDrawer 
             anchor="right"
             open={drawerState}
             handleDrawerState={toggleDrawer}/> 

        </div>
  )
}
```

```
const CartDrawer = (props) => {

 // other stuff at the top 

 return(
    <Drawer
      anchor={props.anchor}
      open={props.open}
      onClose={() => props.handleDrawerState(props.anchor, false)} // annon func here
    />
  )
}
```

The way you have it right now it will fire only once when the component mounts.

```
<MyComponent 
  onClick={handleClick()} // this will always fire on mount, never do this unless you want the result from the function as a prop and not the function as itself
/>
```